# How can I upload from Google Sheets to BigQuery? Can I do it through a Pandas DF?

Tags: pandas, csv, google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

Okay. Let me tell you the long story here. I'm not really a programmer; I basically use Python to make some of my chores easier.

I have been saving RSS feed data at Google Sheets for months (yes, with IFTTT); it has been quite easy, but now it's monstrous in size and hard to query. So, I'm trying to upload those into BigQuery.

The easiest way would be to download as a CSV and then upload to GCS, but it breaks due to characters included in feed item titles. If it recognizes something as an unclosed comma, the CSV blobs together all subsequent values until it recognizes something as a closing comma. If I clean those characters in a text editor, I lose important information in idiosincraticly formatted URLs.

Then I tried uploading from Sheets to BigQuery, setting a "create table" job at the graphical user interface. Should be easy, since the option for importing from Sheets is there. Nope, though. It recognizes the number of columns but imports zip from them.

Then I had the idea of importing the data into a Pandas dataframe on Colab, then doing some cleaning, then uploading to BigQuery. The importing and the cleaning did work, but I didn't find documentation I was able to follow on uploading to BQ.

I tried uploading the dataframe into GCS as a CSV, so I could later upload it to BQ, but forget about it: the same CSV errors happen. I need to bypass CSV as a middleman.

Any ideas of what I could do?